# Решить алгоритмическую задачу на python (подсчет вариантов построения графа)

Tags: python, алгоритм

Не могу решить алгоритмическую задачу. Очевидно здесь какой-то сложный перебор. Можете помочь советом по реализации (какой алгоритм использовать). Буду еще больше благодарен если напишите программку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть есть граф `R` с единственной вершиной степени `n-1`

Его дополнением будет граф `Q` с единственной вершиной степени `0`, т.е. остальная часть графа связна. Дополнение - это такой граф, у которого есть ребро там, где у исходного графа нет связи и наоборот - если у исходного есть ребро, то в дополнении ребра нет. Понятно, что дополнений ровно столько же, сколько исходных графов.

Таким образом, нужно найти **количество помеченных связных графов** `L` с `n-1` вершинами, и **умножит**ь на `n` - т.к. в списке из `n-1` вершин есть `n` мест, куда можно вставить новую вершину.

```
R(n) = L(n-1) * n
```

Проверяем на приведённых примерах: (исключая 1,2 как тривиальные, и для них связность меньшего графа интерпретировать можно по-разному)

```
R(3) = L(2)*3 = 1*3 = 3
R(4) = L(3)*4 = 4*4 = 16
```

Чтобы убедиться в правильности подхода, проверьте, что

```
R(5) = L(4)*5 = 38*5 = 190
```

Это можно сделать брутфорсом - сгенерировать `2^(n*(n-1)/2)` возможных графов и проверить, в скольких из них только одна вершина имеет степень `n-1`

Как найти количество помеченных связных графов? Сами погуглите.

Comment: Огромное спасибо